# Basic questions about $E[E[X \mid Y]]$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables with real values $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$, $\{y_1, \dots, y_m\}$ respectively.

The questions below arose from considering the expression $E[E[X \mid Y]]$ and asking whether it it well-defined and unambiguous.

In my mind, we can make sense of $E[X = x_i \mid Y]$; it is simply $\sum_{j=1}^m y_jP(X = x_i \mid Y = y_j)$. Then $E[E[X \mid Y]] = \sum_{i=1}^nx_iE[X = x_i \mid Y]$.

> $1$. Can we view this as the expectation of the discrete random variable $X \mid Y$ which has values $\{(x_i, y_j) \mid i = 1, \dots, n, j = 1, \dots, m\}$? Or is $X \mid Y$ not a random variable?

Approaching the expression $E[E[X \mid Y]]$ in a different way, I want to swap the order in which we take the expectations.

> $2$. Is $E[X \mid Y = y_j] = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i P(X = x_i \mid Y = y_j)$ a common thing to consider? If not, why not?

Then we would have $E[E[X \mid Y]] = \sum_{j=1}^m y_j E[X \mid Y = y_j]$. Note, this agrees with the other calculation of $E[E[X \mid Y]]$.

In trying to indicate the order of the variables I was taking expectations of, I wrote some expressions which I'm not sure are defined.

> $3$. Does it make sense to write $E[X \mid E[Y]]$ or $E[E[X] \mid Y]$? If so, is there any relation between these things and $E[X \mid E[Y]]$?

Comment: $E[X=x_i|Y]$ makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: (it's because you can only take the expected value of a (random) numerical variable, and true/false is not a number.)

Comment: E[Y] is a number, how does it make any sense to condition on a number?

Comment: $E(X|Y=y_i)$ is a nice sensible concrete quantity.

Comment: OP: The tag (conditional-expectation) seems quite necessary, no?

Comment: @Did: I'd say so. I was unaware of the tag when I asked the question. Thanks for adding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firstly, $E[X=x_i|Y]$ makes no sense

1. $X|Y$ is not an object in the rigorous probability theory sense, but I don't understand what your question means. For discrete random variables (i.e. X and Y only take countably many values), $E[X|Y] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty E[X|Y=y_i]1_{\{Y=y_i\}}$, so $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable.

maybe by $X|Y$ you mean the distribution of $X$ conditional on $Y$? I don't know what the proper notation for this.

1. This is correct
2. $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ are numbers. $E[E[X]|Y]=E[X]$, $E[Y|E[X]]=E[Y]$ What I said was conditioning on $E[Y]$ makes no sense, but thanks to Did and Byron, what I should have said was : conditioning a constant is not particularly interesting or tell you anything

I would like to point out at last that conditional expectations, in the probability theory sense, i.e. $X|Y$, are random variables. These are effectively the 'best prediction' of $X$ when given $Y$.

$E[X=x_i|Y]$ - what should this mean? the expectation of $X=x_i$ conditional on everything you know about $Y$?! The thing before | should be a random variable, but $\{X=x_i\}$ an event. $P(X=x_i|Y)$ or $P(X=x_i|Y=y_j)$ makes sense.

Comment: If you can condition on any discrete random variable, then you can condition on the constant random variable $\mathbb{E}(Y)$.

Comment: Could you explain why $E[X = x_i \mid Y]$ doesn't make sense?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I edited my answer to address this at the end.

Comment: Two points: "X|Y is a random variable" Sorry but no, the object X|Y does not exist. // "conditioning on E[Y] makes no sense" Actually you show later on that it makes sense, only (as you probably mean) the result is not very interesting.

Comment: @Did scrap that comment. what is the proper notation for 'conditional distribution of X on Y'?

Comment: There is no canonical notation. One may want to use $P_X(\ \mid Y)$ if no ambiguity arises. Rigorously though, a conditional distribution is a family of distributions indexed by the state space of the conditioning random variable, hence $(P_X(\ \mid Y=y))_y$ would be more correct.

Answer (score 3):

What you have written in (2) is correct:
  \[
  E[X \mid Y = y_j] = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i P(X = x_i \mid Y = y_j).
  \]
It then follows that $E[X \mid Y = y_j]$ is a function with domain $\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\}$. Let us call this function $h$, so that
  \[
  h(y) = E[X \mid Y = y].
  \]
The object $E[X\mid Y]$ is then defined as $h(Y)$. Note, therefore, that $E[X\mid Y]$ is a random variable. (It is a function of $Y$.) Since it is a random variable, it has an expected value, so it makes sense to talk about $E[E[X\mid Y]]=E[h(Y)]$. We then get
  \begin{align*}
  E[E[X\mid Y]] = E[h(Y)]
  &= \sum_{j=1}^m h(y_j)P(Y = y_j)\\
  &= \sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^n x_i P(X = x_i \mid Y = y_j)P(Y = y_j)\\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\sum_{j=1}^m P(X = x_i, Y = y_j)\\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i P(X = x_i) = E[X].
  \end{align*}
What we have proven here is the general fact that $E[E[X\mid Y]]=E[X]$. I have some more information about conditional expectations of this kind in a [set of notes](http://math.swansonsite.com/instructional/condexp_undergrads.pdf) on my web site.

Comment: By $h(Y)$ do you mean $h\circ Y$, so $E[X \mid Y] : \{y_1, \dots, y_m\} \to [0, 1]$?

Comment: $Y$ is a random variable, so $h(Y)$ is the random variable we get when we plug the random number $Y$ into the function $h$. More precisely, a random variable is a function on the sample space, $\Omega$. In this case, $Y:\Omega\to\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\}$. Also, $h:\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\}\to\mathbb{R}$. So $h(Y)=h\circ Y=E[X\mid Y]$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Of course. Sorry, it has been a while since I've dealt with this stuff.